# How can I copy the code samples from Xcode (14.x) Library window

Tags: xcode, xcode14

When I open up the Library window in Xcode 14. and click on a particular control like the Picker, I see code samples for using the particular control.

I can highlight the sample code text and right click it and choose [Copy] from the context menu (see image).

[image: Xcode Library Code Sample for Picker]

However, when I do that:

1. the context menu flashes away.
2. the Library window disappears

**Sample Code Doesn't Paste In**

Then when I go to Xcode to paste the text in, the sample code does not appear.
Instead, I either get nothing pasted in or the last thing I copied is pasted in.

And, yes, copy / paste works everywhere else on my mac with no problems.

How can I copy that code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could ever copy that sample code was to :

Choose Share -> Notes (see image)

Then open notes and copy it from there and it successfully pasted into Xcode.

[image: Xcode Share to Notes Context Menu]

**Update: Additional Way To Get Code Sample**

I was back in Xcode and I happened to scroll all the way to the bottom of the Picker documentation entry and I found a link that will open the document in Developer Documentation (see red highlight in image).

[image: Open In Developer Documentation link]

If you click that link then Apple Developer Documentation window opens and you can copy the sample code.

[image: apple developer documentation]